# Searchbox is unspecific

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey, i try to write a code that users give the possibility to search words in a textarea. my problem is that the regex does not work.

as example:
if i have "hello stackoverflow" in the textarea and the user search "hello" he recieve on 1 hit and this is correct, but if he search "hello lorem ipsum" he also recieve 1 hit.

```
    regex = new RegExp($("input.search").val(), 'g');
    counter = $("textarea").val().match(regex).length;
```

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = new RegExp($("input.search").val(), 'g');
    counter = $("#textarea").val().match(regex).length
```

**you are missing # in textarea, if you miss that you will get unspecified error**

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
regex = new RegExp("hello", 'g')
"hello stackoverflow".match(regex).length // returns 1
regex = new RegExp("hello lorem ipso", 'g')
"hello stackoverflow".match(regex).length // match returns null
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/nLg2V/